# How to make GridView multicolumn in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, multiple-columns

My GridView in only single column, how can I make it multicolumn?

There isn't an option to set column number in GridView properties.

Update :

[image: The GridView I have]

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You can get the column count with `GridView1.Columns.Count`. But it is read only, you cant add columns with it.

Comment: Okey I updated, thanks

Comment: Then you should modify the source data to include 4 columns, or as @boruchspider suggests, switch to another control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it can be difficult to get a table with 4 columns in a Repeater, here a little example.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.ItemIndex %4 == 0 && Container.ItemIndex > 0 ? "</tr><tr>" : "" %>
                <td><%# Eval("column") %></td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I was trying it. This is exactly what I need - thank you so much

Comment: As you probably already figured out, by changind `%4` you can adjust the number of columns.

Comment: Yes I got, this is great. But what is that line? Lambda or not? Wonderful. Could you give me a resouce for it?

Comment: It called a `ternary operator`. Nothing special, most languages have them. But very useful now and then...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display GridView rows horizontally. A gridview is essentially an html table with each record displayed as new table row.
You can try using a ListView or a Repeater to accomplish what you're trying to do.