# how to display a single column values in multiple columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, aspxgridview

I display the list of table names when a particular database is selected from the drop down list. Number of tables in my database is more than 100. I don't want to display it as a single column and scroll the page. I want to display it as a table. Also each table name is a link to view its corresponding table details. can anyone help me with the technique to achieve it ?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        Tables
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%--<tr>--%>

                <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_TableName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("table_name")%>' /></td>
          <%--  </tr>--%>
        </ItemTemplate>
   <%--     <SeparatorTemplate>
            <td colspan="4"> name</td>
        </SeparatorTemplate>--%>
   <%--     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td> break</td>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>--%>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Switch to a Repeater or ListView and create the columns yourself.

Comment: how to specify the number of columns in repeater control?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45513935/5836671